# Dealing with JSON data returned from a DynamoDB query

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, amazon-dynamodb

I am storing data in a DynamoDb table. I have 3 columns:

**hub_id** (edit: <strike>primary</strike> partition key)

**on_time** (sort key - this is a date time stored as a string)

**details** this contains my JSON data (information from a sensor):

{ "hub_id" : { "S" : "PnKVrm12" }, "temperature" : { "S" : "23" }, "sensor_name" : { "S" : "Tech Lab" }}

Using react-native and aws amplify I can query the table using the following code and return the correct number of rows :

```
  // setup query params
var params = {
TableName : "hiddenprojectv-mobilehub-1542262168-hidden",
ProjectionExpression:"hub_id, details.temperature, details.sensor_name",
KeyConditionExpression: "hub_id = :hid",
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":hid":"PnKVrm12"
    }
};


//execute query using params
db.query(params, function(err, data) {
if (err) {
    console.log("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
} else {
    console.log("Query succeeded.");
    data.Items.forEach(function(details) {
        console.log(details.hub_id,details.sensor_name); 

    });
}
});
```

but I am struggling to get at the data held in the Json object (details column). The query above returns:

16:44:45: PnKVrm12 **undefined**

I expected it to return:

16:44:45: PnKVrm12 **Tech Lab**

for some reason I can never access data in either temperature or sensor_name.

I would appreciate some advice if you have time.

Comment: Not possible for `details.hub_id` to return `PnKVm12` with the given data structure. Explain?

Comment: `console.log(data)` within the callback function and share that with us.

Comment: snip of console.log(data) as requested: https://pastebin.com/mXaE1Zaq

Comment: Right. `hub_id` is on details, but `sensor_name` is on `details.details`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ProjectionExpression` is accessed in your `forEach` loop and provides:

```
details = { hub_id: 'x', details: { temperature: 'x', sensor_name: 'x' } };
```

You are not using your data structure properly. To access the `sensor_name` property you must use:

`details.details.sensor_name'